# Lasso regression, no variable was dropped

Tags: statistics, classification, lasso-regression

I am performing lasso regression in R for binary response variable.

I am using `cv.glmnet` to find the best lambda and using `glmnet` to check the coefficients for the best lambda case. When calling both functions, I specify `standardize =TRUE` and `alpha = 1`.

I have about 40 variables in my case and I am sure some of them are strongly correlated with each other from scatterplots and `vif`(when I was performing logistic regression on the same data).

The best lambda that I got from my lasso regression is <0.001 and no variable is dropped in the best model (with lambda = best lambda).

Wondering why no variable was dropped.

Comment: can you post a reproducible example? how many observations?

Comment: @sahir. It is unfortunate that I could not provide an example that can reproduce the situation. I have about 2000 observations. I finally end up using logistic regression and SVM because I notice that even I manually control the level of lambda (force it to be larger), Lasso regression drop variables arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's because your `lambda` value is too small. `lambda<0.001` means that your penalty is so small that it really don't matter at all. Look at this "stupid" example:

Let's generate some sample random data. Note that variable `z` and `z1` are strongly corelated.

```
library(glmnet)
z<-rnorm(100)
data<-data.frame(y=3+rnorm(100),x1=rnorm(100),x2=rnorm(100),x3=rnorm(100),x4=rnorm(100),x5=rnorm(100),
             x6=rnorm(100),x7=rnorm(100),x8=rnorm(100),x9=rnorm(100),x10=rnorm(100),z=z,z1=z+rnorm(100,0,0.3))
```

Now run some models:

```
gl<-glmnet(y=data$y,x=as.matrix(data[,-1]),alpha = 1)
plot(gl,xvar="lambda")
```

[image]

`lambda` equal `0.001` means `log(lambda)=-6.907755` and even in this "stupid" example where we could think that the coefficients won't be significant (so values should be equal to `0`) we will get small but nonzero values (like in the plot).

Coefficient from `glmnet` with `lambda=0.001` are very similar to those from `glm` (like I said, small `lambda` equal no penalty for log-likelihood):

```
gl1<-glmnet(y=data$y,x=as.matrix(data[,-1]),alpha = 1,lambda=0.001)
gl2<-glm(data=data,formula=y~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7+x8+x9+x10+z+z1) 
gl1$beta
# x1  -0.10985215
# x2  -0.12337595
# x3   0.06088970
# x4  -0.12714515
# x5  -0.12237959
# x6  -0.01439966
# x7   0.02037826
# x8   0.22288055
# x9  -0.10131195
# x10 -0.04268274
# z   -0.04526606
# z1   0.04628616  
gl3$coefficients
(Intercept)          x1          x2          x3          x4          x5          x6 
 2.98542594 -0.11104062 -0.12478162  0.06293879 -0.12833484 -0.12385855 -0.01556657 
         x7          x8          x9         x10           z          z1 
 0.02071605  0.22408006 -0.10195640 -0.04419441 -0.04602251   0.04513612
```

Now look what is the difference on the coefficients from those two methods:

```
as.vector(gl1$beta)-as.vector(gl2$coefficients)[-1]
# [1]  0.0011884697  0.0014056731 -0.0020490872  0.0011896872  0.0014789566  0.0011669064
# [7] -0.0003377824 -0.0011995019  0.0006444471  0.0015116774  0.0007564556  0.00115004
```